# Group data and count the frequencies and create new column based on them in R

Tags: r, group-by

I have data which I want to group based on ID and count the frequencies of occurrences of a column and create new columns based on it. Basically, using `table` command for each ID.

```
ID  status  GPA
1    fail   3.1
1    pass   3.1
1    fail   3.1
1    fail   3.1
2    pass   4
2    pass   4
2    fail   4
3    pass   4.1
```

result:

```
ID   fail  pass  GPA
1     3     1    3.1
2     1     2    4
3     0     1    4.1
```

How can I do it in **R**?

Comment: `aggregate(x$status, list(x$ID), table)` answers the part of your question concerning fail/pass counts. However, it's not entirely clear how aggregate GPA is computed (average? average of successful entries only?)

Comment: thank you. GPA was previously computed and no need for any calculation. just want to keep as extra information for each ID

Comment: To add GPA to 12b...'s solution: `aggregate(DF[2], DF[-2], table)` assuming that status is a factor column.